# Can I use Google Apps Script to create pop-up boxes for when Google Form respondents fill out certain questions?

Tags: google-apps-script, popup, google-forms

I'm creating a Google Form, and would like to include little informational tidbits after respondents finish certain questions— but I'd like the information to be in pop-up boxes rather than part of the questions themselves. Is this something Google Apps Script can help me achieve? I've read that script can only be used to modify what's seen in Google Forms Editor, but not the outward-facing product.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot modify a Google Form to add a pop-up. You can however create a custom form using a GAS Web App but you'll have to build that Form from the ground up using HTML, CSS and client-side Javascript.

Comment: @DimuDesigns—thanks for the info! I had a feeling, but wanted to confirm.